# Facebook Mention Tagging not working

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tagging

Mention Tagging: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/

Here is my code:

```
NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=%@",self.fbAccessToken]];
```

...

```
[self.fbRequest  setPostValue:@"hi, @[555066305] "  forKey:@"message"];
```

But it's not working.It just print "hi, @[555066305] " instead of "hi,@somebody".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you're posting to `/feed` when the tagging / mentions is an Open Graph feature, not a feed post feature.

Secondly, the action type needs to be approved in order to use mentions in the message part, which is mentioned in the documentation along with all the other requirements

Comment: What should I do,if I wanna upload a picture with mention tagging in the description?

Comment: You can use mention tagging in an open graph action which also has a picture attached, but not on a regular photo upload